# "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found" when importing `tensorflow`

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.0

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxMgA.png)I have TensorFlow 2.0 installed and have resolved my 
`Error – Could not load dynamic library ‘cudart64_90.dll’` by downloading and pasting the same file into: *
`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin`.

Now that this issue is clear, I got the subjected error while importing `tensorflow` from Jupyter notebook (GPU).

I tried [the following](https://www.joe0.com/2019/10/19/how-resolve-tensorflow-2-0-error-could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64_100-dll-dlerror-cudart64_100-dll-not-found/).

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Can you please post the entire error with the lines above and below it?

Comment: done. please see image

Comment: Most likely this issue is due to protobuf version. Can you downgrade and check?